# How to use abstract classes in EF

Tags: entity-framework

I have a DbContext class like

```
abstract public class CostCenter
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    abstract public Guid ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    abstract public string CostCenterName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

but i cannot run add-migration and update-database commands its give me error , note abstract class is my need here ,

Comment: Did you try reading the error and searching the web for it?

Comment: Always put the error message in your question.

Comment: SLCloud.Accounting.Data.Context.CostCenter: : EntityType 'CostCenter' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
CostCenter: EntityType: EntitySet 'CostCenter' is based on type 'CostCenter' that has no keys defined.

Comment: This isn't an abstract DbContext class per se, this is an abstract class that you are probably trying to access (directly or indirectly) through a DbContext.

Answer (score 7):

You should derive a new class from `CostCenter` and add the derived class as a `DbSet` to your `DbContext`.

Examples:

```
[Table("SomeCostCenter")]
public class SomeCostCenter : CostCenter
{

}
```

And:

```
[Table("AnotherCostCenter")]
public class AnotherCostCenter : CostCenter
{

}
```

And, on your DbContext:

```
DbSet<SomeCostCenter> { get; set; }
DbSet<AnotherCostCenter> { get; set; }
```

Note that these are set up to use Table-Per-Type (TPT) inheritance to store each derived type in a separate table.  There are other options for this such as Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH) or Table-Per-Concrete class (TPC).  You can search on each of these terms to determine which works best in your scenario.

This might be worth a quick read:
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph